# if $x[n] = (-1)^n$ and $y[n] = (-2)^n$, why the system is not LTI?

Tags: linear-transformations, signal-processing

I am a student and I answered this question "it can be LTI" but my answer was incorrect and the right answer is that this system can't be LTI (Linear time-invariant system).
I don't understand why. could you help me? the question is this:

> If in a system with the input $x[n] = (-1)^n$ we have the answer  $y[n] = (-2)^n$, can this system be LTI?

Why this system can't be LTI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For time-invariant systems, if the input is periodic, then the output [is periodic](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19799/periodicity-of-the-output-of-causal-time-invariant-systems-when-the-input-is-per).

so now if we have an LTI system it means it is time-invariant. and the input is periodic but not the output.

so it can't be LTI.